# How to get a single object`s with Django ORM

Tags: django

Can I extract all the listing data from the Save model where the Save object has two fields and I want to extract the data of the listing only one field

```
def SaveListingView(request):
    context = {}
    listings = Save.objects.filter(user=request.user).only('listing')
    context['listings'] = listings
    print(listings)
    places = listings.values_list('pk', 'price', 'place__image_main_path', 'place__address',
                                      'place__latitude',
                                      'place__longitude')
    context['places_json'] = json.dumps(list(places), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)

    return render(request, 'Main.html',context)
```

This error appears when I execute the query:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Cannot resolve keyword 'price' into field. Choices are: id, listing, listing_id, user, user_id
```

The model:

```
class Listing(models.Model):
  place = models.OneToOneField(Place,on_delete=models.CASCADE,primary_key=True,related_name='listing')
  price = models.BigIntegerField()
  roomsTotal = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(null=True)
  Bathrooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(default=None)

class Save(models.Model):
    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, related_name='Save',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: are you sure this is the view? can you post the entire Save model and the whole error traceback also to the question

Comment: I want all the saved listings for the current user and I could not extract the saved listings how this is done

Comment: ok, look the error you have posted is in this line `places = listings.values_list('pk', 'price', 'place__image_main_path', 'place__address', 'place__latitude', 'place__longitude')` it means the `price` field is not present in the `Save` model

Comment: try `listing__price` instead of `price`

Comment: what to do so I get all the lists saved

Comment: it's work thank you